# Dynamically change element background (gradient)

Tags: javascript, css, draggable

Consider situation http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdGYBN

I need to change background color of card "draggable" dynamically while dragging element.

But card's background should change in accordance with line gradient color.

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,2,2,1) 0%,rgba(242,255,0,1) 34%,rgba(16,255,0,1) 66%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
```

Not like card "badone" that consist all gradients.

Therefore, in top of the container card background should be mostly red. At bottom mostly white.

Any suggestions how to implement this? Hope you understand me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to set `background-size` of the dragged element to size of container and `background-attachment` to `fixed` like so:

```
#draggable {
  background: /* linear gradient */;
  background-size: 900px 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

The `draggability` plugin uses `translate` while dragging and only updates element position after drop. This causes the background to *stick* while dragging. The [jQuery UI Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) changes positions while dragging giving the desired effect.

I've adjusted [your demo accordingly](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGrrxw).

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of draggabilly make use of dragMove event to determine the position of the element while dragging and generate the color value of RGB with a function of height of the line and min and max color
I wrote an **[example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXbjrE)** As per my understanding here 
making the color generation function accurate makes the color of the draggable element more accurate.

```
  [1]: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXbjrE
```